# Laravel Pusher Not Receiving Data at Front End

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, push-notification, push, pusher

It is my First experience with **Pusher**. I am trying to make a test App Laravel 5.2  and Pusher.

> (https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/)

Following above tutorial I configured my Laravel and successfully got the "Channel", "Event" and "Data" from pusher Debug Console.

**Problem:**
When I am trying to get push notification from JavaScript then facing some issues.

```
<script>
            Pusher.log = function (msg) {
//                console.log(msg);
            };
            var pusher = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}")
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
            channel.bind('test-event', function (data) {
//                console.log(data);
            });
    </script>
```

***1.***

`console.log(msg);***` Throwing such a message.

> Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting

```
(index):10 Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"ws://ws.pusherapp.com:80/app/78b26f324ef425bcd2ca?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"}

(index):10 Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"ws://ws.pusherapp.com:80/app/78b26f324ef425bcd2ca?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"}
(index):1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/78b26f324ef425bcd2ca?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
pusher.min.js:12 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4000,"message":"App is encrypted (SSL only)"}}}b.warn @ pusher.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ pusher.min.js:12a.emit @ pusher.min.js:30(anonymous function) @ pusher.min.js:85b @ pusher.min.js:80s @ pusher.min.js:46l @ pusher.min.js:49(anonymous function) @ pusher.min.js:50(anonymous function) @ pusher.min.js:52c.finish @ pusher.min.js:77a.onClosed @ pusher.min.js:77a.emit @ pusher.min.js:30c.changeState @ pusher.min.js:59c.onClose @ pusher.min.js:58a.socket.onclose @ pusher.min.js:59

(index):10 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4000,"message":"App is encrypted (SSL only)"}}}

(index):10 Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/app/78b26f324ef425bcd2ca?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"}

(index):10 Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected

(index):10 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"test-channel"}}

(index):10 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"test-channel"}

(index):10 Pusher : No callbacks on test-channel for pusher:subscription_succeeded
```

**2.**

```
channel.bind('test-event', function (data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

*Throwing Nothing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your log:

> (index):10 Pusher : Error :
>   {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4000,"message":"App
>   is encrypted (SSL only)"}}}

It looks like your Pusher app requires you to connect with SSL enabled. You can find this setting on the Pusher dashboard:

[image: Pusher Dashboard encryption]

To resolve this you need to connect to Pusher like this:

```
var pusher = new Pusher("{{env("PUSHER_KEY")}}", { encrypted: true })
```

Comment: Thank you. Already I have solved the problem. But forgot to replay here.Thanks again.